# Moving wordpress in server giving 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress

I have just uploaded all my WP files in server. I have also updated the database. But I am getting internal server error. The url is : www.worldcon2015.in

Comment: remove .htaccess files and try again

Comment: i have tried that. no luck

Comment: Increasing PHP memory ?

Comment: i have increased it to 64mb.but no result. same error

Comment: When you get a 500 error: always look in the error log of your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have got same kind of problem when I moved my WordPress blog but I solved it myself:

**Here's what I did:**

- I renamed **.htaccess** file to **__htaccess**
- I uploaded an empty file and renamed it to .htaccess
- I changed the permissions on .htaccess to 666 (rw-rw-rw)
- I **set permalinks to a different setting**, saved it, then switched it back to my usual setting.
- Then I changed the .htaccess file permissions back to 644 (rw-r--r--)

I hope this helps you!!